# UWP C# Windows.Web.HttpClient memory leak

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, memory-leaks

I need to periodically send a GET request to a website.

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

   HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
   Uri requestUri = new Uri("https://pastebin.com/raw/1j9EAVUW");

   while (true)
   {
      await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
      await Task.Delay(1000);
   }
}
```

However, running this code causes a memory leak, and RAM usage increase every second.

Applying `using` helps nothing, neither initializing the `HttpClient` inside the loop.

The only solution I came up with was to manually call `GC.Collect()` each loop execution, or each ~10th execution. But I've read it's considered a bad practice.

Is there another way?

HttpClient docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient?view=winrt-19041

Comment: If `GC.Collect()` reclaims memory, then clearly there is no memory leak. You opted for a **non-deterministic** garbage collection scheme, and that's what you get. If you need a system with predictable performance characteristics, you're going to have to go with a programming language that sports deterministic garbage collection, like C++.

Comment: You're correct. I've misused the "memory leak" term. It's just the C# nature. I've rewritten the code in c++ and it works perfectly fine, as the response object gets automatically destroyed when it goes out of scope (one loop execution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient?view=winrt-19041#examples) instance within a `using` statement, the `HttpClient.Dispose()` will be called automatically to free up system resources as soon as the execution exits the scope of the using statement. A high RAM consumption is because the garbage collection has not collected the freed resourced in time. But the garbage collection will collect the freed resources when needed such as allocating other objects or memory condition is low. You could test it by open several **Visual Studio** with solutions, the garbage collection will collect the resources freed from `HttpClient` instances.

If you want to let the garbage collection collect the freed resources positively, you could set [GCCollectionMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gccollectionmode?view=net-5.0#examples) to **Optimized** which instructs the garbage collector to start a collection only if it determines that the collection would be productive enough to be justified.

You could get more information about improving garbage collection performance referring to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/improve-garbage-collection-performance#reduce-memory-allocations).

Comment: Thanks! That's the answer I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is a memory leak. As pointed in the comments, the fact that calling `GC.Collect()` is freeing memory means there is no problem here. The way the garbage collector works in .Net is too long/complicated to explain here but the thing to remember is that collecting garbage is not a cheap operation. In fact, GC might have to pause threads while it collects so .Net will try to wait before collecting and even then it depends on the current memory pressure on the system.

Another thing to note is that calling ````GetAsync(Uri)``` will actually download the entire HTTP response before returning which means it is probably allocating memory to hold the http response. Here's the remarks section in the GetASync documentation:

`This operation will not block. The returned IAsyncOperationWithProgress (of HttpResponseMessage and HttpProgress) completes after the **whole response (including content) is read.**`

If you don't need the content, you can reduce the allocation by telling HttpClient to return once the response headers are read (so it won't allocate memory for the body of the response) and you can also dispose of the response object freeing up any used resources:

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://example.com", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
response.Dispose();
```

Don't worry about adding `GC.Collect()`... leave that to .Net/GC to determine when it is needed.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In case of my project I need to read (and then parse) the response content. I've omitted that to improve the question clarity and put focus on the main problem. You've advised me not to worry about adding GC.Collect(). However, leaving things untouched results in absurdly high RAM consumption after several minutes on execution. Calling .Dispose() can slightly slow down the process, but it's not going to stop that from happening.